# Visual Studio 2010 debugging event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, ocs, office-communicator

I want to write a plugin to Visual Studio 2010 which changes the Office Communicator(OCS) status of a user when s/he startes debugging in Visual Studio. I am familiar with the Client-Side API of OCS but I can't seem to find a proper way to catch the DebugStarted event in Visual Studio.(I also don't know if it has one)

So, do you know any way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you give more details melih?

Comment: hi wolf brother, I think I have dealed with the same issue before. But I don't know if I could access to this small project codes from there.